# Path error while running rabbitmq-server

Tags: windows, erlang, rabbitmq

```
   C:\rabbitmq-server-3.6.0\scripts>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
'realpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
init terminating in do_boot ()
'realpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
init terminating in do_boot ()
'realpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_plugins_main,start,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1053}]},{init,start_em,1[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

`C:\rabbitmq-server-3.6.0\scripts>rabbitmq-server`

```
realpath' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_prelaunch,start,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1053}]},{init,start_em,1[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1034}]}]}}
Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I am using erlang version 7.0 and rabbitmq 3.6.0

I have set environment variables as follows

```
ERLANG_HOME - C:\Program Files\erl7.0
RABBITMQ_SERVER - C:\rabbitmq-server-3.6.0
```

Please Help

Answer (score 29):

For windows

1. Open command prompt
2. change directory to `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server- 
      3.7.12\sbin`
3. type command `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`

Answer (score 0):

Open Start-> Search Edit the environment system variables -> Click on Environment Variables->in Systgem variables search for path variable click on edit-> Click on new and browse to rabitmq directory C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.12\sbin and add the path it will work